# How should  I understand $u_{\infty}$ in this theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I learned the extension of Green's formula to unbounded domains in Kress's *[Linear Integral Equations](http://books.google.com/books?id=R3BIOfKssQ4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (p.71):

**Theorem 6.10** Assume that $D$ is a bounded domain of class $C^1$ with a connected boundary $\partial D$ and outward unit normal $\nu$ and let $u\in C^2({\mathbb R}^m\setminus D)$ be a bounded harmonic function. Then
$$
u(x)=u_{\infty}+\int_{\partial D}\bigg\{u(y)\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y)}{\partial\nu(y)}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\Phi(x,y)\bigg\}ds(y)
$$
for $x\in{\mathbb R}^m\setminus D$ and some constant $u_{\infty}$. For $m=2$, in addition,
$$
\int_{\partial D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}ds = 0
$$
and the mean value property *at infinity*
$$
u_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{|y|=r}u(y)ds(y)
$$
for sufficiently large $r$ is satisfied.

> Here are my **questions**:
>
> - Since the expression $u(\infty)$ may be meaningless, how should I understand the constant $u_{\infty}$ here?
> - [**EDITED:** ] Should the last sentence be interpreted as
>     $$
>   \exists M>0, ~\text{such that}, ~\forall r>M,~ u_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{|y|=r}u(y)ds(y)?
>   $$
> - Do we have
>     $$
>   \lim_{|x|\to\infty}u(x)=u_{\infty}
>   $$
>     [**EDITED:**] i.e.,
>     $$
>   \lim_{|x|\to\infty}\int_{\partial D}\bigg\{u(y)\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y)}{\partial\nu(y)}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\Phi(x,y)\bigg\}ds(y)=0
>   $$
>     in this theorem?

Comment: Yes, I think that was the intended meaning. It's admittedly sloppy, but it's standard to indicate boundary conditions at infinity that way.

Comment: @J.M.: I agree with you. But I think it is not that obvious to see that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u(x)=u_{\infty}$, i.e.,$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{|y|=r}u(y)ds(y).$$